# Help - new Mac keeps crashing

Tags: mac, crash, kernel-panic

I bought a new Mac just over a year ago and it keeps crashing on me. I recently did whole factory reset on it to see if that would help and it just crashed again. Can anyone tell from the error message below what the issue might be? I did upgrade the memory when I first bought it, not sure if the memory is corrupt? I'm still under warranty so I could take it in but thought I would try and see if I could solve it first. Thank you in advance for any help/tips.

```
Hardware Overview:

Model Name: iMac
Model Identifier:   iMac20,1
Processor Name: 10-Core Intel Core i9
  Processor Speed:  3.6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    10
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 20 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   64 GB
  System Firmware Version:  1968.120.12.0.0 (iBridge: 20.16.5060.0.0,0)
  OS Loader Version:    577~170
  Hardware UUID:    B21CC9BE-9458-53F3-A480-4F87ABE8006A
  Provisioning UDID:    B21CC9BE-9458-53F3-A480-4F87ABE8006A
  Activation Lock Status:   Enabled


panic(cpu 9 caller 0xffffff8011794749): Possible memory corruption: pmap_pv_remove(0xffffff955593b300,0x2e3c94000,0x100000, 0x100000000, 0xfffffeba888e24a0): empty hash, priors: 0 @pmap_internal.h:959
Panicked task 0xffffff955312fbf8: 1 threads: pid 6990: com.apple.WebKit
Backtrace (CPU 9), panicked thread: 0xffffff9556167b30, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffe86ec8f7e0 : 0xffffff801166e4fd 
0xffffffe86ec8f830 : 0xffffff80117c30a4 
0xffffffe86ec8f870 : 0xffffff80117b2b29 
0xffffffe86ec8f8d0 : 0xffffff801160e951 
0xffffffe86ec8f8f0 : 0xffffff801166e7dd 
0xffffffe86ec8f9e0 : 0xffffff801166de87 
0xffffffe86ec8fa40 : 0xffffff8011ddc34b 
0xffffffe86ec8fb30 : 0xffffff8011794749 
0xffffffe86ec8fc20 : 0xffffff8011794a71 
0xffffffe86ec8fc70 : 0xffffff801171f05e 
0xffffffe86ec8fde0 : 0xffffff8011721bc9 
0xffffffe86ec8fe40 : 0xffffff8011728174 
0xffffffe86ec8fe90 : 0xffffff80116ad055 
0xffffffe86ec8fed0 : 0xffffff8011b262b7 
0xffffffe86ec8ff30 : 0xffffff8011b260b7 
0xffffffe86ec8ff40 : 0xffffff8011c5ed90 
0xffffffe86ec8ffa0 : 0xffffff801160ed96 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff9556167b30): com.apple.WebKit.WebContent

Mac OS version:
22F82

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:22:22 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B82210B0-6371-3C15-8D2B-47C6E1FB7879
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000011200000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8011400000
Kernel slide:      0x00000000112dc000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff80114dc000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8011300000
System model name: iMac20,1 (Mac-CFF7D910A743CAAF)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 42229124510632
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000026683bf735ba
  Sleep   : 0x00001d6362b23c41 0x00000000a1185376 0x00001d579fda7041
  Wake    : 0x00001d636bdc4409 0x00000000a117545c 0x00001d63681ebd85
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff8084935000 - 0xffffffa084935000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff8084935000 - 0xffffff808c936000
  . VM    : 0xffffff808c936000 - 0xffffff85582cf000
  . RO    : 0xffffff85582cf000 - 0xffffff86f1602000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff86f1602000 - 0xffffff8bbcf9b000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff8bbcf9b000 - 0xffffff9088934000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffff9088934000 - 0xffffff95542cd000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffff95542cd000 - 0xffffff9a1fc67000
  . DATA  : 0xffffff9a1fc67000 - 0xffffffa084935000
  Metadata: 0xfffffff03ab3a000 - 0xfffffff05ab3a000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffff05ab3a000 - 0xfffffff066b3a000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

last started kext at 31795163017025: >!UAudio   540.8 (addr 0xffffff7fa6b3f000, size 335872)
last stopped kext at 32513448631001: >!UAudio   540.8 (addr 0xffffff7fa6b3f000, size 335872)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    6440.7
>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   131
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.1.2
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.1.2
>!AGFXHDA   240.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    340.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 7.1.18
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   7.1.18
>!A!IKBLGraphics    20.0.6
>pmtelemetry    1
@filesystems.nfs    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  198.100.13
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 20.0.6
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   340.1
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
|SCSITaskUserClient 482.120.2
>!UMass!SInterfaceNub   554
>!UCardReader   554
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   627.100.6
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   2142.120.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AUserConsent  1
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    403
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.Compression    1
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>!AHIDKeyboard  231
>!AMultitouchDriver 6440.7
>!AInputDeviceSupport   6440.8
>!AHS!BDriver   6440.7
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1140.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1150.2
>!AAudioClockLibs   240.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6200HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.1.2
|IOAudio!F  440.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>IOHIDPowerSource   1
>!ACallbackPowerSource  1
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!ARSMChannel   1
|IORSM!F    1
>!AIPAppender   1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  7.1.18
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.1.2
@kext.AMDSupport    4.1.2
|IOAccelerator!F2   475.40.6
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGPUWrangler  7.1.18
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    7.1.18
|IONDRVSupport  597
|IOGraphics!F   597
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  336.50.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  10.6.3
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IO80211!F  1200.13.0
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
|IOSerial!F 11
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1150.2
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  554
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  235.100.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  482.120.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  482.120.2
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACyrus    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   5.0.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: I suggest you reinstall the factory memory and see whether there's any improvement.

Comment: Follow what @LincD. stated.  The first line after the “Hardware Overview” section give you a pretty good clue:  “Possible memory corruption.”  It’s important to look over the error report for possible clues

Comment: @LincD. Thank you - by reinstall do you mean physically remove the memory cards and and put them back in the slots? I don't remember there being any software I installed with them.

Comment: @nycmac Yes, remove the RAM hardware modules that you installed and replace them with the ones that cam with your Mac. If you don't have them, try one module, in each slot position; then the other module, and see if things improve.

Comment: When handling memory modules, avoid touching the contacts. Consider cleaning them with rubbing (isopropyl) alcohol and a lint-free cloth.

Comment: @LincD. thank you that seems to have worked so far. I did a whole factory reset and  also reinstalled the memory, fingers crossed.